# Angular2 NgFor bind array in expression

Tags: angular, typescript

The array that is used in the ngfor loop, when it is updated how do you get Angular2 to re-run that expression? Currently it wont output anything due it running at the beginnin with an empty array - once updated (the array has been changed) the ngfor expression is not re-run - which is the desired functionality. How is this done?

For example in the component HTML;

```
<option *ngFor="let user of users" [value]="user.id">{{user.name}}</option>
```

In the component TS we have declared a property;

```
users: IUser[] = [];
```

In ngOnInit we have a call to a TS service that returns us the user data;

```
this.userDataService.getUsers().subscribe(data => {
    this.users = data;
});
```

Updated code example;

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-manage-user',
  templateUrl: './user-form.component.html',
  providers: [UsersDataService]
})
export class UserFormComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private userDataService: UsersDataService) {

  }

  users: IUser[] = []; 

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userDataService.getUsers().subscribe(user => {
      this.users = user;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean with "updated"? When you "update" your array, why not call `this.userDataService.getUsers....` method?

Comment: We can't call getUsers function and assign to the user property directly, because getUsers returns an observable.

Comment: `*ngFor` checks the array for changes every time change detection is run and updates the DOM accordingly. Are you using exactly the `ngOnInit` code above or is it more complex in your real code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ChangeDetectorRef to detect changes.

```
import {ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';
```

Inject it in your constructor and call detectChanges() method when the array's value is changed:

```
  constructor(private userDataService: UsersDataService, private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) {

  }

  users: IUser[] = []; 

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userDataService.getUsers().subscribe(user => {
      this.users = user;
      this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
    });
  }
```

Comment: Ah yes I forgot about the change detector! Thank you very much indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use it like :

```
<select *ngIf="users.length >0">
<option *ngFor="let user of users" [value]="user.id">{{user.name}}</option>
</select
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check because request fast array not update:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.userDataService.getUsers().subscribe(user => {
      if(user){
        this.users = user;
      }
    });
  }
```