# Dynamically inject item to Mat Menu on runtime

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm using the mat menu to display the available options in my project as the breadcrumb. when I'm trying to add a new item, it adds to DB and the array object gets it properly, but the angular mat-menu doesn't update.

This is my reference I'm using:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-nested-topnav-menu-vq6jmd?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Can you tell me how to make mat-menu to load data on runtime?

Comment: The stackblitz is appreciated, but can you simplify it or at least explain how to use it to see the problem you are describing?

Comment: use changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush on your @Component

Comment: just load a json object like navItems and, in subscribe equal this.navItems to the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your response.

My problem is solved. I removed the Child component and I've added it within the parent component and my dynamic data is loaded now.

as in the example I Removed the menu-item component and binded it with in the app component.

Thank you for your time and interest.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays' content change does not trigger Angular's change detection mechanism.

You can either do it by calling detectChanges manually after adding the new item.

```
this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
```

Check this answer for the details:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41298329/11420760

Or you can just reassign your array this will trigger it